# Android use customized dependency in Cordova Plugin?

Tags: java, android, cordova, android-gradle-plugin, dns-sd

I'm using this Cordova plugin for ZeroConf integration:
https://github.com/becvert/cordova-plugin-zeroconf/tree/RxDNSSD

Which one of the Android Java dependencies is RxDNSSD.  Unfortunately there's no way (I can tell) to specify the port to use, so I need to "build" the RxDNSSD dependency from source, so I can modify this line:
https://github.com/andriydruk/RxDNSSD/blob/bce8791516b6ee718cccab346066d55240d56194/dnssd/src/main/jni/mdnsresponder/mDNSCore/DNSCommon.c#L60

To use port `5355` instead.

How can I make it so that when the Android parts are built, that it uses a custom local copy of the dependency (listed as `import com.github.druk.dnssd.DNSSDBindable;`):
https://github.com/becvert/cordova-plugin-zeroconf/blob/RxDNSSD/src/android/net/becvert/cordova/ZeroConf.java#L24-L27

It shows as `com.github.druk.dnssd` ... does that mean it pulls it from GitHub?  Can I somehow have it pull from a custom github repository?

There's a `zeroconf.gradle` file:
https://github.com/becvert/cordova-plugin-zeroconf/blob/RxDNSSD/src/android/zeroconf.gradle

But I can't seem to figure out how I would go about doing this ... if anybody can help shed some light on how to do this, I would be forever grateful :)

Answer (score 0):

Follow this method.

1. Download the plugin git repo. (https://github.com/becvert/cordova-plugin-zeroconf/tree/RxDNSSD)
2. Edit the line you wanted.
3. Push it to your github repo as a public repo.
4. Download the cordova plugin from your repo to your project.

   cordova plugin add <** your git hub repo link**>

Comment: So the problem is that the cordova plugin isn't what needs to be edited, it's the RxDNSSD dependency for Android that needs to be edited

Comment: ok got it. i think you have 2 ways to do that.
1) get the source from github and edit the line and build it as a jar and import it on the config file.

2) get the source edit the lines and publish the library using https://jitpack.io/ . and use it on the zeroconf.gradle

Comment: check this link on how to build a library. 
https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Building-your-own-Android-library